# Method with ? extends Collections<String> is not applicable for Set<String>

Tags: java, generics

Short, self contained, non-compilable example:

```
public void test1() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> a = Collections.singletonMap("One",
            Collections.singletonMap("Two", new HashSet<String>()));
    foo(a);
}

void foo(Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Collection<String>>> x) {
}
```

Yields (javac 1.8.0_102):

```
error: incompatible types: Map<String,Map<String,Set<String>>> cannot be converted to Map<String,Map<String,? extends Collection<String>>>
            foo(a);
                ^
```

I expect `foo` to take any subtype of `Collection` like `Set` or `List`. What is wrong with code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles

```
void foo(Map<String, ? extends Map<String, ? extends Collection<String>>> x)
```

Comment: It does. Care to elaborate why?

Comment: Actually, an [elaborate explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41727663/5899161_) has already been given by other user (+1) and it'd be futile to repeat it. Generics invariance can bite sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

The way you declared foo, the compiler demands a type parameter of the exact type `Map<String, ? extends Collection<String>>`. You could make foo generic:

```
<C extends Collection<String>> void  foo(Map<String, Map<String, C>> x) {
}
```

Comment: Note that the type parameter is used only once in the signature. This reflects the fact that the type parameter is not being used to express any kind of interdependency between the type(s) of the argument(s), the return type and/or throws type. In the absence of such interdependency, generic methods are considered bad style, and wildcards are preferred. (c) jls-4.5.1

Comment: @user2418306 I don't see how you could make an equivalent method declaration using wildcards only. Note that my solution is more strict (closer to your non compiling code) than using `Map<String, ? extends Map<String, ? extends Collection<String>>>`. It does not allow `Map<String, HashMap<String,Set<String>>>` to be passed for example. However it is likely that you actually want the more general wildcard only version.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't compile for the same reason the following (simpler) code doesn't compile:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
foo(l); //The method v(List<Object>) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (List<Integer>)

public void foo (List<Object> a){
...
}
```

The fact that `Integer` extends `Object` doesn't mean that `List<Integer>` extends `List<Object>`. They're two different, unrelated, types.

We can fix the compilation error in the simple case by changing `foo`'s signature to:

```
public void foo (List<? extends Object> a){
 ...
}
```

This tells the compiler that `foo` will be accepting a List of something that extends Object, which is what `List<Integer>` is.

In your case, `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>` doesn't extend `Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Collection<String>>>`.

Even if you changed your `foo` to `void foo(Map<String, Object> x)` it wouldn't compile since `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>` does not extend `Map<String, Object>`. They're two different types.

To get it to work, you can change `foo`'s signature to `void foo(Map<String, ? extends Map<String, ? extends Collection<String>>> x)`